# How To Scrape This Field

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I want the following field, the "514" id. (Id is located in the first row of this webpage)

I tried using xpath with class name and then get attribute, but that prints blank.

Here is a screenshot of the tag in question

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRWrC.png)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/10517/sessions/@timeSlot=Apr08/1')
page_source = driver.page_source
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//li[@class="result clearfix"]')
for el in element:
    id=el.find_element_by_class_name('name').get_attribute("data-id")
    print(id)
```

Comment: Find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71433946/xpath-xpath-is-printing-repeating-value/71434173#71434173

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XPath- XPath is Printing Repeating Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71433946/xpath-xpath-is-printing-repeating-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use find once.

by css - `.result.clearfix .name`

by xpath - `.//*[@class='result clearfix']//*[@class='name']`